# Modifying Alt+Tab behavior

Tags: shortcut-keys, mouse

Ubuntu 15.04

Hi. I'm wondering if it is possible to nullify the influence of the mouse while the Alt+Tab browser is in use. Often times when switching, I don't realize the mouse is positioned over one of the applications in the browser, and the wrong applications is selected.

Also, is it possible to stop similar applications from clustering together? For example, if I have more than one PDF open, the Alt+Tab browser displays them as a collection. To see all of the PDFs, I need to let the browser sit on the PDF collection for a second or two, and then they unfold. This is slow and annoying to me.

Thank you
Matt

Comment: Note that 15.04 is outdated and no longer supported for over a year already. Maybe some behaviour has changed and improved since then. E.g. in 16.04, you have to move the mouse pointer over the Alt-Tab switcher icons to select one. It is not enough if it just sits there already when you open the switcher. And to navigate between windows of the same application, try Alt+^ ("dead circumflex" key, should be right above Tab). You can also use Alt+Tab/^ together to navigate between the windows of different applications.

Comment: You can also hold Alt, press and release Tab, and then navigate through the application icons in the switcher with your cursor keys ←/→. You expand an icon into its windows or collapse them again using ↑/↓ then.